# Changing picture radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a code where picture is displayed based on which radio button is checked. I have written a code with switch sentence but it doesn't seem to work.

I have this code in html:

```
<input name="color" value="grey" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image1')" > image1 
<input name="color" value="image2" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image2')"> image2 
<input name="color" value="image3" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image3')"> image3 
<input name="color" value="image4" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image4')"> image4 

<img id='image' src='' width="400px" height"300px" >
```

and following code in javascript:

```
function changeClr(choice) {

switch(choice){
    case grey: {
        document.getElementById('image').src='./image1.jpg'
    }
    break;
    case image2: {
        document.getElementById('image').src='./image2.jpg'
    }
    break;
    case image3: {
        document.getElementById('image').src='./image3.jpg'
    }
    break;
    case image4: {
        document.getElementById('image').src='./image4.jpg'
    }
    break;
    default: document.getElementById('image').src='./default.jpg'
}
```

Comment: What are the values of grey, image2, image3, etc.? Are there any errors in the console when you click one of the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function changeClr(choice) {
var image = document.getElementById('image');
switch(choice){
    case 'gray': 
        image.src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x400/f00';
        break;
    case 'image2': 
        image.src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x400/0f0';
    break;
    case 'image3':
        image.src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x400/00f';
    break;
    case 'image4':
        image.src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x400/';
    break;
    default: image.src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x400/000';
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="color" value="grey" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image1')" > image1 
<input name="color" value="image2" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image2')"> image2 
<input name="color" value="image3" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image3')"> image3 
<input name="color" value="image4" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image4')"> image4 

<img id='image' src='' width="400px" height"300px" >
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your switch statement you need to check string not the object:

```js
function changeClr(choice) {
  switch(choice){
      case 'grey': {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image1.jpg'
      }
      break;
      case 'image2': {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image2.jpg'
      }
      break;
      case 'image3': {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image3.jpg'
      }
      break;
      case 'image4': {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image4.jpg'
      }
      break;
      default: document.getElementById('image').src='./default.jpg'
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="color" value="grey" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image1')" > image1 
<input name="color" value="image2" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image2')"> image2 
<input name="color" value="image3" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image3')"> image3 
<input name="color" value="image4" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image4')"> image4 

<img id='image' src='' width="400px" height"300px" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning anything to `choice`. If you add the attribute of `id='choice'` to your `input` element, you can do this:

```
var choice = document.getElementById('choice').getAttribute('value');
```

and then pass `choice` as an argument like you're currently doing.

Comment: He is passing value directly in the handler call, but you are right, he can read value from ".value" property

Answer (score 0):

Include quotes:

```
function changeClr(choice) {

switch(choice){
    case 'grey': {
        document.getElementById('image').src='./image1.jpg'
    }
    break;
    case 'image2': {
        document.getElementById('image').src='./image2.jpg'
    }
    default: document.getElementById('image').src='./image2.jpg'
}
}
```

Make sure you are passing right valeue

Answer (score 0):

Treat the var `choice` as string at switch

```js
function changeClr(choice) {

switch(choice){
      case "image1": {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image1.jpg'
      }
      break;
      case "image2": {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image2.jpg'
      }
      break;
      case "image3": {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image3.jpg'
      }
      break;
      case "image4": {
          document.getElementById('image').src='./image4.jpg'
      }
      break;
      default: document.getElementById('image').src='./default.jpg'
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="color" value="grey" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image1')" > image1 
<input name="color" value="image2" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image2')"> image2 
<input name="color" value="image3" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image3')"> image3 
<input name="color" value="image4" type="radio" onclick="changeClr('image4')"> image4 

<img id="image" src="" width="400px" height"300px" >
```

and dont mix **"** with **'** `<img id='image' src='' width="400px" height"300px" >`

use:

```
<img id="image" src="" width="400px" height"300px" >
```